# How to add custom action button in Django admin form and post the information

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-admin

[image]

I'm new to Django!

I'm using Django Admin. How can I make a new button(near save,...) and post the information and use it in a python script(I am using Django version 2).

admin.py:

```
admin.site.register(Router)
admin.site.register(Peer, PeerModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(Prefixe, PrefixModelAdmin)
```

Comment: You can check the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/). It's well explained. Also there's many posts like [this](https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-add-custom-action-buttons-to-django-admin-8d266f5b0d41).
Also duplicated with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723421/custom-actions-in-django-admin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the `change_form_template`. Try like this:

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = 'custom_change_form.html'
```

In `custom_change_form.html` it should be extended from `admin/change_form.html` and it can be like this:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}
    <button> Your Custom Button </button>
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save">
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: thanks do I need to make directory templates/admin/change_form.html?

Comment: no, it should automatically import it from django library.

Comment: I get this error: Could not parse the remainder: '“admin/change_form.html”' from '“admin/change_form.html”'

Comment: You have used single quote and double quote together in  `'“admin/change_form.html”' `, instead use `'admin/change_form.html' ` like described in the answer

Comment: Thanks! still got an error: Invalid block tag on line 4: 'submit_row', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: Well, I am not sure. Maybe you can try my updated answer. hope it helps

Comment: still the same error: Exception Location:  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py in invalid_block_tag, line 534

Comment: Invalid block tag on line 3: 'trans'. Did you forget to register or load this tag

Comment: Oh, you need to load `i18n`. please see my updated answer :(

Comment: this works: {% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}
{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
{{ block.super }}
<div class="submit-row">
<input type="submit" value="Make Unique" name="_make-unique">
</div>
{% endblock %}

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom button to **"Add" form** and **"Change" form** for a specifc admin.

First, about how to add a custom button to **"Add" form** and **"Change" form** for a specifc admin, see [**How to add a custom button at the bottom of "Add" form and "Change" form for a specifc admin**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978362/create-custom-buttons-in-admin-change-form-in-django/73329938#73329938) or [**How to add a custom button right next to "SAVE" button on "Add" form and "Change" form for a specifc admin**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846148/how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-django-admin/73313307#73313307)

Next, set **"response_add()"** for **"Add" form** and **"response_change()"** for **"Change" form** in **"class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):"** to define the action after pressing a custom button as shown below. *Whether or not setting **"response_add()"** and **"response_change()"**, inputted data to fields is saved after pressing a custom button:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = "admin/custom_change_form.html"
    
    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        
        extra_context['custom_button'] = True
        
        return super().changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):

        if "_custom_button" in request.POST:
            # Do something
            return super().response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)
        else:
            # Do something
            return super().response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        
        if "_custom_button" in request.POST:
            # Do something
            return super().response_change(request, obj)
        else:
            # Do something
            return super().response_change(request, obj)
```